# For the title alone

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

Someone has voted for [one of my questions](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/11402/diana-stanley-dreams-of-a-sunken-city) with this comment:

> +1 for the title alone.

Which of these two possible meanings is the most correct:

- The title itself is so nice that I would have voted for the question whatever it was
- I vote for your title, but your question doesn't deserve it

Comment: I'm sure Tim meant the first of your two options. I think it would be perverse of a commenter to use this form intending the second meaning, and perverse of anyone else to assume that meaning, so this question seems Too Localised to me.

Comment: To get the second meaning, you'd have to use *only*, or reword using *but*. This construction with *alone* always gets you the first meaning.

Comment: The question begs to be placed in Meta.

Comment: @RegDwighт: Your answer is crystal clear

Comment: @FumbleFingers: My concern is to understand the meaning outside the context of stackexchange

Comment: @rajah9: I first wrote a question on "for *something* alone". I added the context (stackexchange) before posting only to help to answer.

Comment: @PhilippeBlayo, You are asking a question that is about neither the English language nor usage. It should be asked in Meta because it is a question about the *forum* for the English language, not the English language itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest asking that in a comment of your own after the +1 comment, but my interpretation is more like your first alternative than the second: that the title  is  nice enough by itself to get an upvote, so long as the question is not a major loser.  That is, if the question had been really bad, I suspect a good title would not have been enough to trigger an upvote.

I see no implication of  “your question doesn't deserve it” in the comment.